# Form Validation errors in PHP

Tags: php, forms, server

I have made a simple form tried to do validation on it but keep getting few errors like undefined indexes. Here is the code:

```
<?php

//echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,true).'</pre>';

$display_result = false;

$form_data = [

    'name' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'flavor' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'cakesize' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'filling' => [
        'value' => [],
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'agree' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],
];

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $name = trim ( $_POST['name'] );
    if (empty($name) ) {

        $form_data['name']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['name']['err_msg'] = "Please enter a name";
    }

    else {

        $form_data['name']['value'] = $name;
        $form_data['name']['error'] = false;
    }


    $flavor = $_POST['flavor'];
    if ( empty($flavor) ) {

        $form_data['flavor']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['flavor']['err_msg'] = "Please select a flavor";
    }

    else {

        $form_data['flavor']['value'] = $flavor;
        $form_data['flavor']['error'] = false;
    }

    $cakesize = $_POST['cakesize'];
    if( empty($cakesize) ){

        $form_data['cakesize']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['cakesize']['err_msg'] = "Please select the size";
    }

    else {
        $form_data['cakesize']['value'] = $cakesize;
        $form_data['cakesize']['error'] = false;
    }

    $filling = $_POST['filling'];
    if( empty($filling) || count($filling) < 2 ) {

        $form_data['filling']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['filling']['err_msg'] = "Please select atleast 2 fllings";
    }

    else {
        $form_data['filling']['value'] = $filling;
        $form_data['filling']['error'] = false;
    }


    $agree = $_POST['agree'];
    if( empty($agree) ) {

        $form_data['agree']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['agree']['err_msg'] = "Tick the box if you agree to the terms and conditions";
    }

    else {
        $form_data['agree']['value'] = $agree;
        $form_data['agree']['error'] = false;
    }
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cake ordering Form</title>

        <style>

            .reqd {
                color: red;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="" method="post" id="cakeForm">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal Details</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Your Full Name: <span class="reqd"><?php print 
                    $form_data['name']['error'] ? $form_data['name']['err_msg'] : '' ?></span></label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Make Your cake!</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="flavor">Select your flavor: <span class="reqd"><?php print 
                    $form_data['flavor']['error'] ? $form_data['flavor']['err_msg'] : '' ?></span></label><br />
                    <select id="flavor" name="flavor">
                        <option value="0">Select Flavor</option>
                        <option value="yellow" >Yellow</option>
                        <option value="white">White</option>
                        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
                        <option value="combo">Combo</option>
                   </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Size of the cake: </label><br />
                    <label><input type="radio" name="cakesize" value="round6"/>Round cake 6" -  serves 8 people <br /></label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="cakesize" value="round8"/>Round cake 8" - serves 12 people <br /></label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="cakesize" value="round10"/>Round cake 10" - serves 16 people <br /></label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="cakesize" value="round12"/>Round cake 12" - serves 30 people <br /></label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Fillings: </label><br />
                    <label class="checkFill"><input type="checkbox" name="filling" value="lemon"/>Lemon <br /></label>
                    <label class="checkFill"><input type="checkbox" name="filling" value="custard"/>Custard <br /></label>
                    <label class="checkFill"><input type="checkbox" name="filling" value="fudge"/>Fudge <br /></label>
                    <label class="checkFill"><input type="checkbox" name="filling" value="mocha"/>Mocha <br /></label>
                    <label class="checkFill"><input type="checkbox" name="filling" value="raspberry"/>Raspberry <br /></label>
                    <label class="checkFill"><input type="checkbox" name="filling" value="pineapple"/>Pineapple <br /></label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>


            <p>
                <label class="inlinelabel"><input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" /> I agree to the terms and conditions </label>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
            </p>


        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help....

Comment: You need to assign value as false for `$form_data['name']['error']` and all. When you load your page its not getting any value.

Comment: the value for $form_data['name']['error'] is already false.....$name and $flavor is working fine...only trouble with the rest

Comment: can you share use `error notification` ?

Comment: Undefined Index: cakesize
Undefined Index: filling
Undefined Index: agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isset()` or `empty()` to check postdata is set or not. Use below code.

```
<?php

//echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,true).'</pre>';

$display_result = false;

$form_data = [

    'name' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'flavor' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'cakesize' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'filling' => [
        'value' => [],
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],

    'agree' => [
        'value' => '',
        'error' => false,
        'err_msg' => '',
    ],
];

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $name = trim ( $_POST['name'] );
    if (empty($name) ) {

        $form_data['name']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['name']['err_msg'] = "Please enter a name";
    }

    else {

        $form_data['name']['value'] = $name;
        $form_data['name']['error'] = false;
    }


    $flavor = !empty($_POST['flavor']) ? $_POST['flavor'] : "";
    if ( empty($flavor) ) {

        $form_data['flavor']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['flavor']['err_msg'] = "Please select a flavor";
    }

    else {

        $form_data['flavor']['value'] = $flavor;
        $form_data['flavor']['error'] = false;
    }

    $cakesize = !empty($_POST['cakesize']) ? $_POST['cakesize'] : "";
    if( empty($cakesize) ){

        $form_data['cakesize']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['cakesize']['err_msg'] = "Please select the size";
    }

    else {
        $form_data['cakesize']['value'] = $cakesize;
        $form_data['cakesize']['error'] = false;
    }

    $filling = !empty($_POST['filling']) ? $_POST['filling'] : "";
    if( empty($filling) || count($filling) < 2 ) {

        $form_data['filling']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['filling']['err_msg'] = "Please select atleast 2 fllings";
    }

    else {
        $form_data['filling']['value'] = $filling;
        $form_data['filling']['error'] = false;
    }


    $agree = !empty($_POST['agree']) ? $_POST['agree'] : "";
    if( empty($agree) ) {

        $form_data['agree']['error'] = true;
        $form_data['agree']['err_msg'] = "Tick the box if you agree to the terms and conditions";
    }

    else {
        $form_data['agree']['value'] = $agree;
        $form_data['agree']['error'] = false;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: `isset()` will allow empty values, `!empty()` would be better.

Comment: yes.. you are right. I have changed it. @PedroLobito

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you do check `$_POST` isset before assign. i.e.

```
$flavor = isset($_POST['flavor']) ? $_POST['flavor'] : NULL;
```

For checkbox may not submitted if unchecked, it will cause undefined for this case.

Comment: hello @ruchishParikh my form validation script that you modified, why is it that we must check the set value first of $flavor, $cakesize and $agree before setting its value?? please provide me a clear understanding regarding this if you don't mind...thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php Go to this link its provide you all information about it. @AbhijitBorkakoty